# Java equals method - no operator, no operand - if(equals(null))

Tags: equals

I found some code on the Eclipse site posted by an Eclipse guru:

```
String something = null ;       
if (equals(null)) {
    System.out.println("b'");
}
```

It compiles. But it does not appear to run.

What kind of *java* code is this?

Comment: Code will not compile unless you have equals method in the class or have done static import of some class containing equals method or this code is written in non static method in the class. 

I do not see any usage of this code apart from occupying some space in stack and eating some cpu time

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan: that is always true.

Answer (score 1):

`equals()` is an ordinary method declared in the `Object` class.

Like any other method in your class or base classes, you can call it on `this` with an operand.
`equals()` is equivalent to `this.equals()`.

Calling `equals(null)` can never return true, because you can't call a method on a `null` instance.

Answer (score 0):

It does run, but it may not be obvious! Give the following code a try:

```
if (equals(null)) {
    System.out.println("b");
} 
else {
    System.out.println("c");
}
```

With this code, you should see the letter `c` on your standard out.

---

[`equals(Object obj)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) is a method declared in the `Object` class.

`equals(someObject)` is equivalent to `this.equals(someObject)`.

`equals(obj)`'s API contract is:

"*`true` if `this` object is the same as the `obj` argument; false otherwise.*."

In your example code, the `obj` is not `this` object but `null`. Therefore, the `if` clause evaluates to `false` and therefore the executing virtual machine won't evaluate `System.out.println("b");`.